# No thread-safety between different vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-safety, std

My problem deals with the usage of different vectors at the same time. I know I can't expect the same vector to work in multiple threads simultaneously. I've broken down the program so it is easier to understand it. I have a `ThreadClass` class that has a constructor which just adds an element to the vector `k` and then calls a thread `toCall` which then outputs the size of the vector which is supposed to be one. The object of this class is created inside of a different vector inside of the `main()` function using vector's `push_back` member.

The output turns out to be 0. Sometimes I can get 1 as well. I can produce more of the number 1 if I switch to debug mode. I have tested this problem on a gnu C++17 compiler (Ubuntu 16.04) and a Visual Studio compiler (Windows 10). My question is now if this example shows that I should avoid using vectors in multi-threaded programs totally?

```
class ThreadClass 
{
private:
    std::vector<int> k;
    std::thread thr;
public:
    ThreadClass() {
        k.push_back(27);
        thr = std::thread(&ThreadClass::toCall, this);
    }
    void toCall() {
        std::cout << k.size() << std::endl;
    }
    void close() {
        if (thr.joinable())thr.join();
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<ThreadClass> lols;
    lols.push_back(ThreadClass());
    lols[0].close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a value of type `ThreadClass` holds a reference to itself.  Specifically, `thr` contains a copy of `this`.

When you copy or move such a value, e.g. when the temporary `ThreadClass()` is moved into `lols`, the duplicate holds a duplicate `this` ptr, i.e. it points to the old temporary, whose lifetime ends after the call to `lols.push_back` finishes.

We can replicate this problem without threads:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::vector<int> k;
    Foo* possibly_this;
public:
    Foo() {
        k.push_back(27);
        possibly_this = this;
    }
    void toCall() {
        std::cout << possibly_this->k.size() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Foo> lols;
    lols.push_back(Foo{});
    lols[0].toCall();
}
```

(For me, it prints 0 with -O0 on 7.3.1, but again, it's UB, so it could do anything on your machine.)

`lols.emplace()` will *not* help.  If a `std::vector` resizes, then all pointers/iterators into it are invalidated.  Unfortunately, you can't change the pointers stored in `thr`, so you're left with one solution: disable `ThreadClass`'s copy and move constructors, like so:

```
  //within the definition of ThreadClass
  ThreadClass(ThreadClass const&) = delete;
```

In order to place `ThreadClass` in a container, you will need an additional level of indirection to allow the actual object of a value of type `ThreadClass` to have a stable location.  Either `std::list<ThreadClass>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ThreadClass>>` will do the trick.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, this explanation enlightened me.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your thread can call `toCall` before the constructor returns. It's not a good idea to go creating threads that call back into the object in the constructor. Defer the thread creation to some kind of `start` or `launch` function and call that after the constructor returns.

This is also a problem:

```
lols.push_back(ThreadClass());
```

Here, the destructor (of the temporary) can even run before `toCall` gets called! That's definitely not going to work. That's another really good reason not to create a thread in a constructor -- it makes temporary objects disastrous.

Comment: Thanks. I have taken your suggestion and it works fine now. But I am not sure about your second part. From my understanding it can always happen that a desctructor is called before a thread gets called. For example you have a function called `CallMyThread()` which calls a thread inside of the object. Then suddenly the desctructor gets called for whatever reason.

Comment: @SouthParkGermany So then maybe the destructor should ensure that the thread finishes before it returns.